# jPanel Colour not changing in JAVA GUI Application

Tags: java, swing, arduino, jpanel, rxtx

I have made a JAVA GUI application with Netbeans. It uses RXTX library to communicate with Arduino. It's all working fine. The program is able to get the serial outputs from Arduino. The arduino send strings 0 or 1 repeatedly after a one second delay. I made the program such that if it receives 0, it colors the jPanel as red and if it gets 1, it colors the jPanel as  green. Also, 2 buttons also color the same jPanel. But when running program, when i press the buttons, they color the jPanel as i want. But the if statement on 0 & 1 is not able to color the jPanel. I have checked by putting some other statements that the if condition loop is working fine but still it is not able to set color of jPanel.
Here is my code-

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
public class tets extends javax.swing.JFrame implements SerialPortEventListener {
SerialPort serialPort = null;

private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
 //       "/dev/tty.usbmodem", // Mac OS X
//        "/dev/usbdev", // Linux
//        "/dev/tty", // Linux
//      "/dev/serial", // Linux
    "COM3", // Windows
};

private String appName;
private BufferedReader input;
private OutputStream output;
private static final int TIME_OUT = 1000; // Port open timeout
private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600; // Arduino serial port
String inputLine;
public boolean initialize() {
    try {
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        // Enumerate system ports and try connecting to Arduino over each
        //
        System.out.println( "Trying:");
        while (portId == null && portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            // Iterate through your host computer's serial port IDs
            //
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            System.out.println( "   port" + currPortId.getName() );
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if ( currPortId.getName().equals(portName) 
                  || currPortId.getName().startsWith(portName)) {

                    // Try to connect to the Arduino on this port
                    //
                    // Open serial port
                    serialPort = (SerialPort)currPortId.open(appName, TIME_OUT);
                    portId = currPortId;
                    System.out.println( "Connected on port" + currPortId.getName() );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (portId == null || serialPort == null) {
            System.out.println("Oops... Could not connect to Arduino");
            return false;
        }

        // set port parameters
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                        SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                        SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                        SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        // add event listeners
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

        // Give the Arduino some time
        try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}

        return true;
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}



public synchronized void close() {
    if ( serialPort != null ) {
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
    }
}

//
// Handle serial port event
//
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    //System.out.println("Event received: " + oEvent.toString());

    try {
        switch (oEvent.getEventType() ) {
            case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE: 
                if ( input == null ) {
                    input = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                serialPort.getInputStream()));
                }
                inputLine = input.readLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                startx(inputLine);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
}
/**
 * Creates new form Parking
 */
public tets() {
    initComponents();
    appName = getClass().getName();
}
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    panel1 = new java.awt.Panel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel1);
    panel1.setLayout(panel1Layout);
    panel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 250, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    panel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 206, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jButton1.setText("connect");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("jButton2");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(70, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(panel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(80, 80, 80))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(107, 107, 107)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(158, 158, 158)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(panel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(15, 15, 15)
            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jTextField2.setText("Parked");
        panel1.setBackground(Color.RED);
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    panel1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    jTextField2.setText("Free");            
}                                        

private void startx(String inputLine){
    int a = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
    Color color;
    if (a == 0){
        color = Color.RED;
        panel1.setBackground(color);
    }
    else{
        color = Color.GREEN;
        panel1.setBackground(color);
    }
    System.out.println(color);
    panel1.repaint();

}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
      tets test = new tets();
     if ( test.initialize() ) {
        try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
    }
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(tets.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(tets.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(tets.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(tets.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new tets().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private java.awt.Panel panel1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: You're creating two frames `tets test = new tets(); .... new tets().setVisible(true);`, one that you set to be visible and one that is not visible. Also, I think you're blocking the EDT with the `Thread.sleep(2000);` calls.

Comment: I tried to do this, but again no results.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here. If needed, simulate the `0` and `1` stream with a `SwingWorker`.

Comment: Also, if the changes come quickly the pane might not repaint since the repeated calls are collapsed into one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be due to serial port event not being processed on EDT.
What if you wrap the startx(inputLine) call in SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    startx(inputLine);
            }
    });
```

See if that works.

Edit : The problem is that you are recreating the instance of tets in the main method when you make it visible. So, the initialized instance is not even used. Use the already created instance of tets (Replace **new tets().setVisible(true);** to **test.setVisible(true)** in main method, you will have to change the variable test to be final.) along with above suggestion (to use invoke later) and it will work.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But not as i wanted. It opens the window when it receives from the port and then change the color. But I want that the and receiving from port & changing color goes parallel.